# How can I upload or delete files to multi-ftp servers

Tags: ftp

Is there a program for upload or delete files to multi-ftp servers.

eg.

```
Ftp sites:
  ftp.a-site.example
  ftp.another-site.example

Command:
  DELETE a-file From All FTP SITES
Or:
  DELETE a-file or selected-file From all-selected-sites
```

Comment: I've never seen one. Sounds like an incredibly dangerous idea, though. I'm curious why you want this.

Comment: [BeanStalk](http://www.beanstalkapp.com) allows you to deploy your code to multiple servers. It doesn't sound like you're using version control, so you can kill two birds with one stone here.

Comment: Other solutions for deploying to multiple servers are discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96405/deploying-to-multiple-servers).

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to mirror files and directories on multiple servers?

If so and the servers you are using are LAMP stacks you could utilize Lsyncd to sync the folders in near real-time. That way when you upload files to Server A they are copied to Server B. The same applies to deleting files as well. I use this type of setup for redundancy with my company's cloud servers.

Here's a [lsyncd setup walk-through](http://www.thisisnotsupported.com/lsyncd/) that should help if this the type of functionality you're looking for.